# passing value from jquery function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to pass two values, from one jquery listing function, to another function.
The first value is a row from a table, the second is a select option value, here is my code :

```
function ListDBValues() { 
 if (!window.openDatabase) { 
  alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.'); 
  return; 
 }
$('#lbUsers').html(''); 
db.transaction(function(transaction) { 
   transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM productos;', [], 
   function(transaction, result) { 

      if (result != null && result.rows != null) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) { 
          var row = result.rows.item(i); 
          $('#lbUsers').append('<div id="producto"><img id="imgprod" width="100" src="images/' + row.foto +'">' + row.titulo + '<br>$' + row.precio + ' MXP<br>\
          <input class="cuadro" type="button" id="cb.row" name="item"  value="ORDENAR" onclick=AddValueToOrders('+ row.item + ','  + cantidad.val() + ');>\
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
          <label for="select-choice-a" class="select">Cantidad:</label>\
          <select name="cantidad" id="cantidad" data-native-menu="false">\
          <option value="1">1</option>\
          <option value="2">2</option>\
          <option value="3">3</option>\
          <option value="4">4</option>\
          </select></div></div><br>');

        } 
      } 
     },errorHandler); 
 },errorHandler,nullHandler);
 return; 
}
```

Any comments ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: which values ? to where ? if the value are defined in a callback function you need to define a function outside the callback and call it in the callback to get the value , that's called an event loop.

Comment: Hi : I'm trying to pass the row.item value (alone is passing ok) but also nee to pass the value of "cantidad" (select option), and are going to AddValueToOrders('+ row.item + ','  + cantidad.val() + '). But I dont know how to send the value of cantidad ?, thank you

Comment: Are they string values? In that case, try enclosing them in `""`. Like : `onclick=AddValueToOrders("'+ row.item + '", "' + cantidad.val() + '")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the function you are referencing :

```
AddValueToOrders('+ row.item + ','  + cantidad.val() + ');
```

Your append statement has some issues that need to be addressed. Every select control will have the same name and id, making it difficult to figure out the selected value. If you create an index-based id for each of the select elements and reference that in your function call, then you will get the selected value:

```
      var cantidad = "cantidad" + i;
      $('#lbUsers').append('<div id="producto"><img id="imgprod" width="100" src="images/' + row.foto +'">' + row.titulo + '<br>$' + row.precio + ' MXP<br>' +
      '<input class="cuadro" type="button" id="cb.row" name="item" value="ORDENAR" onclick=AddValueToOrders('+ row.item + ', $("#' + cantidad + '").val());>' + 
      '<div data-role="fieldcontain">' +
      '<label for="select-choice-a" class="select">Cantidad:</label>' +
      '<select name="' + cantidad + '" id="' + cantidad + '" data-native-menu="false">' +
      '<option value="1">1</option>' +
      '<option value="2">2</option>' +
      '<option value="3">3</option>' +
      '<option value="4">4</option>' +
      '</select></div></div><br>');
```

The new onclick function:

```
AddValueToOrders('+ row.item + ', $("#' + cantidad + '").val());
```

Comment: Hi Sam: thank you for your comment, it sound logical to me. I tried it but I'm receiving a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token", I'm already reviwed the function, but I dont found the error, here is again :

Comment: I changed the wrapping style of your example, so it might be that your editor is not recognizing it the same way. You were using backslashes at the end of each line, and I changed to concatenation.      Look for syntax errors around the jquery selector for the select control in your onclick function.    ---    Also, be sure an select an answer to your questions by upvoting the best choice - feedback is awesome.